# Prime factorization of a large number

Tags: math, cryptography, mathematical-optimization, factorization

I need help on figuring this out by hand so that I may apply it to code. I need to find the prime factorization of this large number utilizing some sort of an algorithm. I have tried Fermats Little Theorem and also looked into Elliptical Curves, however nothing seems to click. The number is 589449600

Comment: Seems more like a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about elementary arithmetic, not computer programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about prime factorization and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime factors are 2, 3, 5, 97 and 211.

This can be found quickly by trial division of basic primes.

Comment: Thank you ! I will Google trial division to see exactly how it works, I really need to understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

This online calculator has a description attached. Try this:

> Example: Consider the number N=147:
>   the prime numbers less than
>   N=147 are 2,3,5,7,11,13,... To find the
>   decomposition into a product of prime factors of 147, begin by
>   attempting the division by 2, 147 is not divisible by 2. Then
>   divide by 3, 147/3=49 so 147 is divisible by 3 and 3 is
>   a prime factor of 147. Then, no longer consider 147 but
>   147/3=49. The prime numbers less than 49 are
>   2,3,5,7,11,13,...2,3,5,7,11,13,..., try to divide 49 by 2 and so
>   on.

source http://www.dcode.fr/prime-factors-decomposition

Comment: "the prime numbers less than" is larger than necessary, the upper limit if primes that need to be tested is the square root of the prime. In this case of 147 test primes less than sqrt(147) or <12 so test 2,3,5,7,11. Then primes < sqrt(49) or <= 3,5,7 (2 has been exhausted) and so on.